# Load an Iframe with cross origin domain with google chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

I'm developing a chrome extension for gmail application and i want to load our web application content through iframe. But i'm getting blocked frame even though, we add content secuirity policy tag in manifest.json. What is the right way to implement loading of cross origin domain content with iframe in gmail chrome extension?

Here is the error that i'm getting.

> Refused to frame 'example.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' https://clients4.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/ https://calendar.google.com/accounts/ https://ogs.google.com https://onegoogle............etc.

**Manifest File:**

```js
{
  "name": "gmailext12",

  "version": "1.0.0",

  "manifest_version": 2,

  "description": "gmailext12",

  "icons": {
    "16": "images/16.png",
    "128": "images/128.png"
  },

 "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["scripts/background.js"]
  },

 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/16.png"
  },

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'shakey' https://example.com; frame-src 'self' 'shakey' https://example.com; object-src 'self'",


  "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
    ]

}
```

**Content.js**

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

// Must be declared at web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
iframe.id = 'gmail-pega123';

// iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('iframe.html');

iframe.src = 'https://example.com';

// Some styles for a fancy sidebar
iframe.style.cssText = '`enter code here`';


document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: @wOxxOm edited my question.

Comment: 1. You can modify gmail's CSP header using chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived (google up the examples), 2. You can insert an iframe pointing to your extension's html page (declared in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)) and then inside it insert an iframe to that site (you'll probably need to add the site to `frame-src` in [content_security_policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)).

Comment: If I do first one, will it impact any gmail default behaviour? It will impact rite?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it should impact gmail behavior. A page can't check if its CSP has been tampered with. A problem could arise only if that site is malicious and the user receives an email that contains images linked to that site and the user has agreed to show the images in that message.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm Will extension be allowed to publish in chrome web store if we do like this? I mean, loading cross origin sites into gmail's view?

Comment: If this functionality is one of your extension's primary functions and it's explained in the description clearly, I see no problems. The reviewers like single-purpose extensions, they don't like extra functions not related to the main function, as well 
 as undeclared behavior.